# Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: php, google-chrome

К каждой ссылке добавляю `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` и когда пытаюсь нажать по ссылке выдает ошибку `Not allowed to load local resource` раньше было все нормально. код

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'./index.php'; ?>">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Женская одежда</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Детская одежда</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Одежда для пары</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: _SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] - это путь на диске, где у вас установлен продукт (http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php). Это не BASE_URL сайта. И немного странно, как он мог работать раньше. Разве что, есть его значением была пустая строка. На крайний случай можно использовать _SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], но с указанием протокола. В вашем случае, думаю, стоит совсем убрать _SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Comment: @Vitaly Сделайте из этого ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - это путь на диске, где у вас установлен продукт (php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php).

Это не BASE_URL сайта. И немного странно, как он мог работать раньше. Разве что, есть его значением была пустая строка. На крайний случай можно использовать `_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, но с указанием протокола.

В вашем случае, думаю, стоит совсем убрать `_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.